# How to connect two layout java android?

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, connection

I'm beginner in Java Android developing. I'm using Eclipse SDK 3.6.1 version. I'm trying to do this thing: I have one layout named "login.xml" and other "main.xml". I want first load "login.xml", input login name and then if login name correct load "main.xml".

```
public class simpleprogram extends Activity {   


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

}
```

How to call main.xml correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to change the layout. You should create a separate activity with content view == R.layout.main(similarly to how you have done with `simpleprogram` activity) and start the activity in the moment of successfull login.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         // check that login is correct
         // if so...
         Intent intent = new Intent(simpleprogram.this, SecondActivity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
      }
    }
}
```

Refer to the original developers [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you could also just set a new contentview after commit?

```
public class simpleprogram extends Activity {   


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(checkForLoggedIn()){
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }else{
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
    }

}
```

Or do something similar with an onClick

Answer (score 0):

you have to type :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.login);
   Button loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginBtn);
   loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     // check that login is correct
@Override
   public void onClick(View args0) {
   setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
   }
}
}
```